# What's the correct way to tentatively switch to a wait cursor in Win32? (Or: How to trigger WM_SETCURSOR properly?)

Tags: c, winapi, mouse-cursor

Here's the problem I'm having:

- I need to switch the cursor to (say) `IDC_WAIT` until I'm done performing some action.
- `SetCursor` is only effective before the mouse moves.
- `WM_SETCURSOR` is only effective after the mouse moves.

You would think I could just do *both* of the above, calling `SetCursor` and modifying the behavior of `WM_SETCURSOR` simultaneously so that I get the cursor to change until some point in the future.

But I can't just do that. Why? Because `SetCursor` is application-wide, yet a random window has no idea (nor should it) what the correct cursor is *across the entire application*. It would need to perform the proper hit-tests to send a `WM_SETCURSOR` to the window that is actually under the cursor, and it's unclear what the right way to do that is.

What's the right way to switch cursors and back in Win32? Every example I see is trivial and ignores these problems.

Comment: Application-wide is what you want.  Use GetCursor(), SetCursor(), slow stuff that hangs the message loop, SetCursor() to restore.  If the slow stuff doesn't actually hang the message loop (it isn't clear) then it gets a wholeheckofalot harder since all child windows have to co-operate to keep the hourglass.  Usually only practical in a framework, compare to Winform's Control.UseWaitCursor.

Comment: @HansPassant: Even if I do it application-wide, the cursor still needs to remain unaffected when I'm (say) resizing a border or hovering over an edit box, otherwise it's confusing as heck. And it simply doesn't make sense that a 1-pixel movement would suddenly cause a change when the operation is still in progress, so I still have this problem even if I'm willing to immediately call `SetCursor` to change it application-wide. Nothing here hangs the message loop—this is a background operation on another thread that the main thread is starting/stopping—but how do people make this work?

Comment: They don't, popping up a "working on it" dialog is the standard approach.

Comment: @HansPassant: Funny you mention that, that's exactly what I'm trying to get rid of since it's so user-unfriendly and unnecessary to block the UI or pop up an extra window for what I'm doing. So there's really no good solution? :( If so feel free to post that as an answer...

Comment: It gets more friendly by visibly disabling the control(s) that can't safely be used when the worker thread is chomping away.  Like the button that started it.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm adding to a list, and everything in that list is perfectly usable while it's being appended to. The *headers* might not be usable, but that's about it. I can come up with other ideas, but for the purposes of the question I'm just wondering what I can do about the cursor.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with calling `SetCursor`. it provides immediate feedback. If the user moves the mouse over something that's not disabled the cursor changes back to normal again. The user is used to the cursor changing as they move it around so I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: There are at least 2 problems with it. First one is that if they're e.g. resizing the window, the cursor shouldn't suddenly change, period. Second one is that even if I just do it anyway, what would I revert the cursor to when the operation is finished? It's going to be over a totally control and I have no idea what the correct cursor is for that control so I can't just restore the original. (Imagine if I restored an I-Beam when it's over a list view...) What I *really* need to do is to trigger `WM_SETCURSOR` for whatever's underneath the cursor and then it decide the cursor.

Comment: Is the first problem really likely? It would be unusual for a blocking operation to commence while the user was doing something modal like resizing a window. As far as the second problem goes, I don't think there's any reason you can't send a `WM_SETCURSOR` message to the window under the cursor yourself.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes it's likely. It's only "unlikely" if you imagine the operations being blocking & long. I have long & short ones  in the background, and there's no reason the user can't resize a window during that time. Not that the problem would be any different even if the user was hovering over the border and not actively resizing. As for the second one, that's what I'm writing the code for right now (calling `WindowFromPoint` and doing the hit-test and all manually...); I was trying to answer your question of why you shouldn't blindly call `SetCursor`.

Comment: I kind of agree with Hans that the cursor may not be the best way to indicate activity given that it's going to indicate background activity the user didn't directly initiate. Maybe some sort of "spinner" graphic in the corner might be better. Anyway the design of your app is up to you :)  But I'm not sure there's an easy way to test if the cursor is currently a standard arrow (and therefore safe to change), which sounds like the missing piece of your puzzle.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I will have other indicators too, but they don't substitute for each other in every situation, and I don't really want to debate it here. Actually it's harder than you imagine because even if it's not an arrow, sometimes I'd still need to change it. (e.g. `IDC_APPSTARTING` should still change to `IDC_WAIT` too.) And given multiple operations may finish out of order, figure out what to revert to is not obvious. I am writing code for this, and while I do have something, it's inherently nontrivial & race-prone & incomplete, and it seems `WM_SETCURSOR` isn't handled consistently.

Comment: It does seem to be a complicated problem, requiring a co-processing of cursors on all controls in the program. In short, please feel free to update your thread if there is any progress.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT: Yeah... what shocks me is why is there zero *hint* of a discussion on this on the internet as far as I can see. I'd have thought this is such a well-known problem that it'd have a clear solution in the community... surely I'm not the first person to try to care enough to get this right after nearly 3 decades?! Cursor changes are so common that all I can imagine is that everyone who cared enough was working on a niche or commercial program and didn't bother asking on a forum anywhere. And part of it is a special case of a more general problem with coherent state toggling too.

Comment: Just to rule out the last bit of ambiguous wording, do I understand this correctly? You want that, in *every possible case*, the cursor is solely determined by the specific window that is directly underneath the cursor (e.g. a specific button)? In other words, you *always* know exactly what to do in your `WM_SETCURSOR` messages (and you have implemented that successfully), but if you ever want to set the cursor *outside* of a `WM_SETCURSOR` message, you don't know what the cursor should really be because now you're not same control as the one where the mouse currently is located?

Comment: @dialer: I think so? Though I'm not currently writing the code for a control, but for an entire window/dialog (though I might need to do that too), and yet I think it does matter what is under the cursor (e.g., IMHO a button and an edit box should cause different responses), and I don't even know if there is a convention out there for what should have priority and whatnot, so I'm coming up with prioritization rules on the fly myself. And I'm trying to generate & send `WM_SETCURSOR` manually, but it's not behaving consistently and I'm still trying to debug if the bug is related to it or not.

Comment: @dialer: At a high level my question isn't necessarily "what is the code for *this particular operation*" but rather "how do people solve these cursor-setting problem in general", because it might be that I'm just trying to do the wrong operations to begin with and there are established practice for changing cursors coherently, I don't know.

Comment: That's sort of what I was getting at. I think the reason this seems complicated is because it will be just as complicated as you want it to be. Many devs don't pay much attention to such details and never tested thoroughly whether the cursor is correct in every possible case. It'll right itself eventually through `WM_SETCURSOR` messages. They probably never call `SetCursor` outside of `WM_SETCURSOR`. An end user would only notice that if they intently stare at the cursor without moving it. The API can't help much either since it doesn't know how complicated you decided it to be in your case.

Comment: It sounded like you pretty much already had the simple solution. There is already kind of a "priority system" in place: The fact that the `WM_SETCURSOR` message goes to the "innermost" control first. If that control doesn't have a strong opinion on what the cursor should be, it can ask its parent for a "lower priority" choice (in fact, that's what the `DefWindowProc` does). `GetCursorPos` + `WindowFromPoint` + Sending a `WM_SETCURSOR` whenever you think the cursor state could have changed should take care of the rest. If that's buggy for you, then maybe that's another question.

Comment: (contd) You need to take the captured window (`GetCapture`) into account.

Comment: @dialer: The priority system you're talking about isn't the one I'm talking about. I'm talking about priority between cursors, you're talking about priority between controls. I might have two tasks that dictate different cursors for the same window; which one to choose (especially if they finish out of order) is nontrivial and requires keeping explicitly track of priorities. I know in theory it should be as simple as sending `WM_SETCURSOR`, but in reality it's not that simple. The ordering as well as `SendMessage` vs. `SendMessageCallback` matters. I'm discovering all these as I go right now.

Comment: @dialer: And I'm testing out cursor changes from other threads, and messages aren't necessarily even pumped when I expect them to be (and vice-versa!), so cursor changes don't occur when I expect and I have to figure out why. Blocking has perf implications too. If I knew what was a bug and what was a fundamental limitation that might require me to change my approach, I wouldn't be asking about the canonical solution here. I can't really describe how non-obvious it is in reality to figure out what's really going on... you just have to try this approach on a non-toy app to see what I mean.

Comment: No that is exactly what I mean by *it will be as complicated as you decide it to be*. If you have a window that can have one of several different cursor states (regardless of whether it's top-level or not), then at any point in time that window must be ready to receive a `WM_SETCURSOR` and (quickly) be able to tell what the cursor should be. The code that goes in there has *absolutely nothing to do with the winapi*, or any perceived complications thereof. It can be as simple as `if (data->Prio1TaskRunning) SetCursor(A); else if (data->Prio2TaskRunning) SetCursor(B);`. (cont...)

Comment: (contd) The data required for this decision must be readily available to the UI thread. If that is not true then the synchronization of your application state is messed up. Regarding threads, if you manipulate UI from multiple threads, *you are doing it wrong*. [Many APIs have hidden thread affinities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110207-00/?p=11563) and you *will* dig yourself into a hole. Solely your UI thread is responsible for updating UI state. If another thread does something that might require a UI update, it must first update shared data, then (cont...)

Comment: (contd) post (not send) a message and let the UI thread sort itself out. And yes, messages are not necessarily processed in order for several reasons, [here is one of them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130531-00/?p=4203). Regarding priorities: I understood what you mean, but you didn't understand me. The system gives you everything you need. When the cursor is over a control, that control can set the cursor. Or it can forward it to its parent. It could even ask its parents what the highest priority cursor of its ancestors is (recursively), and make the decision based on that.

Comment: @dialer: I just posted an answer.

Comment: @Strive Sun - MSFT: I posted an answer, in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

1_ Implementing busy cursor is easiest when it is combined with disabled input. First disable input `EnableWindow( hwnd, FALSE );` and then set busy cursor `SetCursor( LoadCursor( 0, IDC_WAIT ) );`. Now you can do some operation (ideally not longer than 5 seconds). After that enable input `EnableWindow( hwnd, TRUE );`. When your operation takes longer than 5 seconds, window will be "ghosted", so it would lose busy cursor on title bar and sizing borders.

2_ If window needs to accept input when displaying busy cursor, you have to handle `WM_SETCURSOR` message not only in window procedure of your top level window, but also for all its children (simple `STATIC` controls are an exception). This requires subclassing (`SetWindowSubclass`) of these children, which can be rather though task unless you can use some advanced framework.

In subclassing window procedure, just set busy cursor and return `TRUE`. Do not call `DefWindowProc` or `DefSubclassProc` for `WM_SETCURSOR` case.

```
switch ( message )
{
case WM_SETCURSOR:
    SetCursor( MyCursor );
    return TRUE;
...
}
```

Subclassing can be done on each child creation or at later time, by enumerating them.

Interestingly it works even for menu and combo boxes with popup lists.

3_ Another option would be to hide cursor `ShowCursor( FALSE );` and display instead semitransparent window tracking mouse cursor position with some click through capability. Personally I would start with window displayed just few pixels above or below current cursor position.

Maybe progress bar on status bar or simple animation (hourglass?) on main window would be easier.

Comment: I don't and can't unfortunately, the entire purpose is to leave the app still usable while I'm doing the operation. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Can't work, WM_SETCURSOR is sent, not posted.  So can only be intercepted in the window procedure.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. I have checked my old source code and custom framework automaticly subclasses all controls so `if ( msg == WM_SETCURSOR )` is in one single procedure, not message loop. So unfortunatelly this answer is wrong.

Comment: @user541686 I have changed my answer so it could be more useful. I have verified options 1, 2 and 3. At least on Windows 10 they work.

Comment: @DanielSęk: I don't know if I need to go the subclassing route but it does seem like a possibility. Thanks for the update. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that kind of works reasonably. It's not perfect (I do still see some rough edges), but I think it's okay for me so far and behaves more reasonably than the lazy approach given all the trade-offs.

**Your mileage may vary depending on the complexity of your app.**

Here's what I'd suggest doing to someone in a similar situation:

1. Define an app-wide message, e.g. `WM_UPDATECURSOR = WM_APP + 0`.
2. Have your main (GUI) thread process `WM_UPDATECURSOR` by triggering `WM_SETCURSOR`:

   a. Use `GetCursorPos` and `WindowFromPoint` to get the thread under the cursor.

   b. Use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to check the process and thread IDs.

   c. If it's in a different process, stop.

   d. If it's in a different thread from your process, `PostThreadMessage(thread_id, WM_UPDATECURSOR)` to it, then stop. (This is **highly** unusual and generally poor practice; I'm only mentioning it for completeness.)

   e. If it's for your own thread, then use `WM_NCHITTEST`, and if it succeeds, figure out (as explained further below) what the *correct* cursor should be, if anything. If anything, set it with `SetCursor`; if not, `SendMessage(WM_SETCURSOR)`.
3. Keep a list of counters corresponding to different cursors that you consider "stackable". Earlier elements are *lower* priority. Anything that isn't in the list will not be overridden or considered later.
4. Whenever you want to change the cursor on any thread, increment or decrement its corresponding counter, atomically if needed. (It is assumed this cursor is in the list of stackable cursors.)
   Then trigger a cursor update in the same manner as for `WM_UPDATECURSOR` above.
5. To figure out if a cursor has been stacked at any point, go through the list in reverse, and find the cursor corresponding to the first positive counter. If there is none, then return `NULL`; there is no stacked cursor.
6. In your main window/dialog's `WM_SETCURSOR` handler, evaluate the cursor from the global list as explained in the previous step, and use `SetCursor` to set it. However, **return `FALSE`** so that child windows (like Edit controls) still override it if they want to.

I'll update this if I figure out more issues, but I think overall it behaves decently.

Comment: As mentioned before, if the mouse is captured, Windows stops sending `WM_SETCURSOR` messages. The immediate implication of this is that if the mouse moves outside the capturing window while it's still captured, the mouse cursor still behaves as it did at the time of capture inside the window. In that case, querying the cursor from the window beneath the mouse position would result in different behavior.

Comment: @dialer: As mentioned in the answer, it's not perfect and still has rough edges...